# ADSL router - public IP for local network

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

Today I went to my friend and took a look at his PC. He has ADSL router ZTE ZXDSLl 831cii. So there is a telephone line to router and PC is connected to Lan1 of the router (there are also Lan2, Lan3, Lan4).

When I opened his PC network settings I saw the following: Address type - DHCP, IP - 89.41.xxx.xxx, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, gateway:89.41.xxx.xxx. I was surprised as I never saw in local network such settings. Local network as I thought that Lan1,Lan2,Lan3,Lan4 are one local network (which as I know must be one of 192...,10...,172...).

So I have two questions:

1. How to explain such strange ip address?
2. If I want to connect to this router the second host what network settings should I set for this second host?

Comment: That is a public IP. It looks like he has a dial-through connection. Check the settings on the router to see how the connection is established and what the network settings are.

Comment: That's totally possible to get a public ip via DHCP, just not as common as getting a private IP from a local DHCP server.  For a second host, set the connection to DHCP and let it auto negotiate another Ip.

Comment: Check the settings on the Lan page http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZTE/ZXDSL-831CII/Advanced_LAN.jpg

Comment: I would verify that is his public IP with ipchicken or similar service. I have definitely seen private LANs misconfigured and using public IP ranges in private space. It usually comes to light when a can't reach a website only from inside their network. Just a possibility

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the router / adsl modem is in bridge mode.

It will pass Internet ip's from your ISP to the local computers, rather than having your router provide private IP's to the lan.

There is probably a setting to turn the router or modem back to router mode.